# HTTP to HTTPS redirections

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have added ssl for site and now i wanna use redirect in htaccess.

I have this one in htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,QSA]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What and where should i add for redirect?
Th for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code in your .htaccess file automatically redirects visitors to the HTTPS version of your site:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And where i should paste this code in my code?

Comment: Is it OK? `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @Narkomax, you need to add this in you .htaccess file and put the file in your project root folder.

Comment: I mean add code that you type before all my code or after? I mean where past this small piece

Comment: @Narkomax Just updated the code. Please check that.

Comment: This is what ended up working for me

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

Answer (score -1):

You should paste this .htaccess file into your project root.